# Problems with my javascript, I dont want to validate <select> tags that are disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

This javascript will find all my selects and validate them but I want to add that it doesnt validate my disabled selects. How can I code that in my javascript?

```
$("#next-step").click(function () {

                var $step = $(".wizard-step:visible"); // get current step

                var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
                var anyError = false;
                $step.find("select").each(function () {
                    if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                        anyError = true;
                    }


                });

                if (anyError)
                    return false; // exit if any error found
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add a test to see if the element has the "disabled" property set to `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!this.disabled && !validator.element(this)) {
    anyError = true;
}​
```

or (slower)

```
$step.find("select:enabled").each(function() {
    if (!validator.element(this)) {
        anyError = true;
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, i know of is to give the select tags, a class like `skipvalidation` and then

```
$("form").validate(
   ignore: ".skipvalidation"
);
```

You can find all the disabled elements and add the class as

```
$("input:disabled").addClass("skipValidation");
$("form").validate(
   ignore: ".skipvalidation"
);
```